# Can I take a screenshot from the devtools console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Devtools has a "command menu" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) which offers the ability to take a screenshot of the site / selected node. Is there a way to access this functionality through the devtools console?

Comment: Weird workaround: undock devtools into a window, press Ctrl-Shift-i to open devtools-on-devtools, open its console and run Emulation.DeviceModeView._wrapperInstance._captureScreenshot()

Comment: Devtools-on-devtools is the maze of confusion in which the screenshot function is called, you can see the code there, but it's not simple to decipher. You can press `Ctrl-Shift-i`, then `Ctrl-Shift-i`, then `Ctrl-Shift-f`, then you can search for `screenshot` and you will find a bunch of places where it is mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to access this functionality through the devtools console?

DevTools tech writer here. To answer your question narrowly, no, this is not possible.

Puppeteer is a good solution for automated screenshots.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.3.0/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions