# Run Chrome Dev tools commands programatically in console to take node screenshots

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for a way to programatically take screenshots of multiple HTML nodes on a page.
Under console you can take a screenshot by doing `Command + Shift + P > Capture node screenshot`.

Does Dev tool have an equivalent command for the same? Something like:

```
nodes.forEach( ( node ) => Chrome.api.commands.nodeScreenshot( node ) );
```

where `nodes` is a NodeList.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. It would be nice to be able to create Chrome Dev Tools snippets that can save screenshots to the disc.

Comment: I don't suppose either of you ever found a way to do this in the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I take a screenshot from the devtools console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012807/can-i-take-a-screenshot-from-the-devtools-console)